# How can I open a MIME-formatted file?

Tags: mime-types, xdg-open, file-types

On several distributions of Linux, there is a utility called `xdg-open`, which opens a file in the default application for that particular file type. E.g., for HTML files, it might open `firefox`.

A MIME-formatted file contains data and meta-data within a single file, with the meta-data occurring in key/value pairs at the beginning of the file. A MIME-formatted file is very similar to an HTTP response. E.g., here is a MIME-formatted HTML page.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html

This is a <em>small</em> HTML document,
located within a MIME file.
```

1. Is it possible to use `xdg-open` or some other utility to open this file with the default application?
2. Is there a MIME viewer? E.g., that can display common content types, like `text/plain` and `text/html`?

It seems to me like there are varying approaches to tracking file meta-data. E.g., there are "sidecar" files, the Mac OS X operating system has filesystem-level "resource forks", Windows uses file extension to determine file type, etc, etc. Wouldn't it be easier if the existing MIME standards were more closely integrated into *nix operating systems?

Comment: That looks like an email header to me. Why not open it with an email client. Alternatively you could dump it to a file with `<html><body>` at the start and `</body></html>` at the end and open it in a browser.

Comment: `file --mime-type -b /path/to/file` will determine the MIME typing of a file.  What you do with the response is up to you, but a script with a simple set of `case $mimetype in [...] esac` should fit the bill.  More generally, `file` is the tool to determine what type of file something is, so that you can deal with it as apropos of its type.

Comment: There are arguments to be made against the complexity of MIME, e.g. https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-8873 or https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-7209